# How do I add a Splash screen to a main program in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I have 2 files, Splash.java and Main.java. Here are the 2 codes:
Splash.java

```
package application;

import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;


/**
 * This is my own splash screen, that I made myself.
 *
 */
public class Splash{
    static Stage splash;
    static Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    public Splash() {
        splash = new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        splash.toFront();
        splash.setHeight(200);
        splash.setWidth(400);
    }
    public Splash show() {
        /*
         * Part 1:
         * This is the rolling square animation.
         * This animation looks cool for a loading screen,
         * so I made this. Only the lines of code for fading
         * from Stack Overflow.
         */
        //rectangle insertion
        int scale = 30;
        int dur = 800;
        rect = new Rectangle(100-2*scale,20,scale,scale);
        rect.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);

        //actual animations
        //initialising the sequentialTranslation
        SequentialTransition seqT = new SequentialTransition(rect);
        //umm, ignore this, just some configs that work magic
        int[] rotins = {scale,2*scale,3*scale,4*scale,5*scale,-6*scale,-5*scale,-4*scale,-3*scale,-2*scale};
        int x,y;
        for (int i:rotins) {
            //rotating the square
            RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(dur),rect);
            rt.setByAngle(i/Math.abs(i)*90);
            rt.setCycleCount(1);
            //moving the square horizontally
            TranslateTransition pt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(dur), rect);
            x=(int) (rect.getX()+Math.abs(i));
            y=(int) (rect.getX()+Math.abs(i)+(Math.abs(i)/i)*scale);
            pt.setFromX(x);
            pt.setToX(y);
            //parallelly execute them and you get a rolling square
            ParallelTransition pat = new ParallelTransition();
            pat.getChildren().addAll(pt,rt);
            pat.setCycleCount(1);
            seqT.getChildren().add(pat);
        }
        //playing the animation
        seqT.play();
        //lambda code sourced from StackOverflow, fades away stage
        seqT.setOnFinished(e->{
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            KeyFrame key = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(800),
                           new KeyValue (splash.getScene().getRoot().opacityProperty(), 0)); 
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(key);   
            timeline.setOnFinished((ae) -> System.exit(1)); 
            timeline.play();
        });
        //The text part
        Label label = new Label("Flight");
        label.setFont(new Font("Verdana",40));
        label.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white");
        label.setLayoutX(140);
        label.setLayoutY(70);
        Label lab = new Label("Launching...");
        lab.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",10));
        lab.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white");
        lab.setLayoutX(170);
        lab.setLayoutY(180);
        //A complimentary image
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("launchplane.png"));
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(image);
        iv.setFitWidth(32);
        iv.setFitHeight(32);
        iv.setX(174);
        iv.setY(130);
        //now adding everything to position, opening the stage, start the animation
        Pane pane = new Pane(rect,label,lab,iv);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black");
        Scene sc = new Scene(pane);
        splash.setScene(sc);
        splash.show();
        seqT.play();
        return this;
    }
}
```

And Main.java

```
package application;    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add( getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("Flight");
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("airplane.png")));
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            Splash splash = new Splash();
            splash.show();
            primaryStage.toBack();
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a Splash screen appear before the main program is launched. How do I modify Main.java so that my code can show the splash screen for its entire duration before fading away and opening the main program?

Comment: See [this tutorial](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/09/javafx-how-to-easily-implement-application-preloader-2/) about setting up a splash screen via JavaFX preloader.

Comment: I will try and see. Thank you!

Comment: @Vulcan Once I have set the Splash into the Preloader, how do I start the main application?

Comment: I've never used the Preloader launcher before but that tutorial supplies an example Main class, does that answer your question?

Comment: To a limited extent, yes.

Comment: @Vulcan the problem is they are opened in quick succession.

Comment: As far as I understand, that tutorial example causes the splash stage to stay visible until Application class' `init` method finishes execution. You could try doing a thread sleep in that init method for the amount of time you'd like the splash screen to appear, though this approach seems hacky and likely not what the preloader class was designed with in mind.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/sedj601/SplashScreenTest) is my way of doing a `splash screen`.

Comment: Updated my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code. I changed the `Splash` variable to `Scene`. I then added methods to get the `Scene` and the `SequentialTransition`. I set the `SequentialTransition`  onFinished method in the main.
.

> Main

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication266 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Splash splash = new Splash();
        splash.show();
        stage.setScene(splash.getSplashScene());
        splash.getSequentialTransition().setOnFinished(e -> {
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            KeyFrame key = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(800),
                    new KeyValue(splash.getSplashScene().getRoot().opacityProperty(), 0));
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(key);
            timeline.setOnFinished((event) -> {
                try {
                    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
                    //
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

                    stage.setScene(scene);
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            timeline.play();
        });
//
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Splash Class

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * This is my own splash screen, that I made myself.
 *
 */
public class Splash
{

    static Scene splash;
    static Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    final private Pane pane;
    final private SequentialTransition seqT;

    public Splash()
    {
        pane = new Pane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:black");

        splash = new Scene(pane);
        seqT = new SequentialTransition();
    }

    public void show()
    {
        /*
         * Part 1:
         * This is the rolling square animation.
         * This animation looks cool for a loading screen,
         * so I made this. Only the lines of code for fading
         * from Stack Overflow.
         */
        //rectangle insertion
        int scale = 30;
        int dur = 800;
        rect = new Rectangle(100 - 2 * scale, 20, scale, scale);
        rect.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);

        //actual animations
        //initialising the sequentialTranslation
        //umm, ignore this, just some configs that work magic
        int[] rotins = {scale, 2 * scale, 3 * scale, 4 * scale, 5 * scale, -6 * scale, -5 * scale, -4 * scale, -3 * scale, -2 * scale};
        int x, y;
        for (int i : rotins) {
            //rotating the square
            RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(dur), rect);
            rt.setByAngle(i / Math.abs(i) * 90);
            rt.setCycleCount(1);
            //moving the square horizontally
            TranslateTransition pt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(dur), rect);
            x = (int) (rect.getX() + Math.abs(i));
            y = (int) (rect.getX() + Math.abs(i) + (Math.abs(i) / i) * scale);
            pt.setFromX(x);
            pt.setToX(y);
            //parallelly execute them and you get a rolling square
            ParallelTransition pat = new ParallelTransition();
            pat.getChildren().addAll(pt, rt);
            pat.setCycleCount(1);
            seqT.getChildren().add(pat);
        }
        //playing the animation
        seqT.play();
        //lambda code sourced from StackOverflow, fades away stage
        seqT.setNode(rect);
        //The text part
        Label label = new Label("Flight");
        label.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 40));
        label.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white");
        label.setLayoutX(140);
        label.setLayoutY(70);
        Label lab = new Label("Launching...");
        lab.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", 10));
        lab.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white");
        lab.setLayoutX(170);
        lab.setLayoutY(180);
        //A complimentary image

        Image image = new Image("https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.eremedia.com/uploads/2012/08/24111405/stackoverflow-logo-700x467.png");
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(image);
        iv.setFitWidth(32);
        iv.setFitHeight(32);
        iv.setX(174);
        iv.setY(130);
        //now adding everything to position, opening the stage, start the animation
        pane.getChildren().addAll(rect, label, lab, iv);

        seqT.play();
    }

    public Scene getSplashScene()
    {
        return splash;
    }

    public SequentialTransition getSequentialTransition()
    {
        return seqT;
    }
}
```

> After Splash Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

> After Splash FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication266.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Thank you @Sedrick! I made some other workaround for my project but thanks for the help!